# Codeigniter and PHP. Using POST to access array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am building an API using Codeigniter and Phils RESTserver and I am trying to send an array to the API using a POST request.

When I POST this:

```
query=("email@example.com","anna@nicole.com")
```

I can access it like this:

```
$this->post('query');
```

This produces:

```
("email@example.com","anna@nicole.com")
```

How can I loop through these email addresses in PHP?
Do anyone got another idea?

Thankful for all input!

Comment: Would this work? `explode(',', str_replace(array('(',')'),'',$emails))`

Comment: Perfectly! Thanks. Make it a real answer and I will give you points and choose as best answer.

Comment: But this is not an answer, it's just a comment. Also, maybe there is a better way to improve what you want.

Comment: Maybe it's better use square brackets, like this: `["email@example.com","anna@nicole.com"]`. This way you'll have array in `$this->post('query')`. But since you haven't provided the code you use to perfrom post, it's hard to tell, whether it would work or not.

Comment: If I use this ["email@example.com","anna@nicole.com"] how can I then loop through it on the server side? Why is this better? I am posting with the Firefox extension RestClient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are controlling the POST request, then you should POST an array to PHP, not a delimited list, which will automatically create an array that is available for use when the server receives the request. This is what J0HN means when he says use square brackets instead of parenthesis.

However, it depends on how you're sending the request to the server to determine the proper way to send an array to PHP. You might need:

1. query=["one@example.com", "two@example.com"]
2. query[]=["one@example.com", "two@example.com"]
3. Or other variants...

Since you don't elaborate on how you're making the request to the server, the proper way to POST an array cannot be determined.

On the other hand, if you can't POST an array for some reason, you can always send a JSON-encoded string and easily decode it:

```
// Assuming $this->post('query') = json_encode( array( "one@example.com", "two@example.com"));    
$emails = json_decode( $this->post('query')); // Array of emails
```